# How to store the contents of a bitset variable to a uint32 in c

Tags: c++

I need to find a way to take a sequence of bits in a bit set variable and assign them to a uint32 variable in c++.

For example if I have a bitset<32> variable of "0xffff ffff" I would like to have a uint32 variable of ffff ffff.

I once had the sequence of bits as a string representation but I decided to hold the bits using a bit set. Would it be easier to transfer them from a string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bitset` has a [`to_ulong`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/to_ulong/) method to do just that:

> `unsigned long to_ulong() const;`
>   **Convert to unsigned long integer**
>   Returns an `unsigned long` with the integer value that has the same bits set as the bitset.

Example:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::bitset<32> b(0xffffffff);
    uint32_t i = b.to_ulong();

    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Build & run:

```
$ make example && ./example
c++     example.cpp   -o example
11111111111111111111111111111111
ffffffff
```